# Проект javafx в среде NetBeans

Tags: javafx, netbeans

В Windows10 установил jre1.8.0_261, jdk-13.0.2, NetBeans 11.0. Пробую создать проект javafx. Среда не протестует, создает шаблонный проект, но он не компилируется. Жалуется на отсутствие файла jdk.../bin/javafxpackager. Есть рекомендации применить файл javapackager, но ни тот ни другой файл нигде не могу найти. Скачал javafx-sdk-15, но и там ничего похожего. Кроме того, NetBeans отказывается принять этот пакет как дополнительную платформу (add platform). Все рекомендации, что нашел, даже в Oracle, касаются старых версий sdk и NetBeans. Вопрос: как в 2020 г. программировать в javafx? Может есть более подходящая IDE?

Comment: Использую Intellij IDEA с JavaFx, никаких особых проблем нет. Бесплатной Community версии вполне достаточно. С NetBeans не работал, поэтому сравнить не могу. P.S. по вашей проблеме - попробуйте использовать [JDK от Bellsoft](https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/) - Javafx в него входит.

Comment: @insolor Спасибо! Оба варианта стоит попробовать.

Comment: Однако ничего не получается. IDEA жалуется на jdk, в том числе тот, который сама грузит. В JDK от Bellsoft никакой поддержки FX нет. В  javafx-sdk-15 нет архива для javafx.application и некоторых других. Отдельно jar-архивы нигде не могу найти. В решении проблемы не продвинулся.

Comment: При скачивании нужно Full JDK нужно выбирать https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtuB3.png

Comment: @insolor Спасибо, друг!

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена благодаря insolor. Надо грузить JDK Bellsoft (Full JDK, msi-файл сам установит системную переменную), перезагрузить комп. В новом проекте установить SDK соответственно. И не читать бред от Oracle: "For JDK 11 and later releases, Oracle has open sourced JavaFX".
NetBeans и IDEA успешно построили и скомпилировали свои шаблонные проекты.

Comment: `И не читать бред от Oracle: "For JDK 11 and later releases, Oracle has open sourced JavaFX"` - ну вообще-то JavaFx сейчас Open Source проект, не вижу тут никакого бреда.